# Intel QuickSync error : Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, centos, intel, transcoding

I want to make IPTV with a topology like this:

Restream / source -----> IPTV server -----> User

The problem at the moment is the question of bandwidth that is still large.

Finally I announced by IPTV software providers to transcode with Intel QuickSync video and FFmpeg.

I followed the steps given by the software provider at the following link:
http://www.ezhometech.com/document/intel_ffmpeg.txt

Which comes from the link below:
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-paper...

I installed IPTV software on a laptop with an Intel processor, chipset and VGA.

```
[root@iptv ffmpeg-4.1]# **lspci**
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

[root@iptv ffmpeg-4.1]# **lspci -nn -s 0:02.0**
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
```

but when I do a transcoding test, an error always appears :
**Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.**

Error details :
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/vp9XIzbeOuyXRuLBlLfSng

FFmpeg log:

```
./ffmpeg  -hwaccel qsv -i http://premium-play.org:8000/domm0H56Cj/q3ODLP6C16/2826 -vcodec h264_qsv -acodec copy -b:v 1200K -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:9011?pkt_size=1316
ffmpeg version 3.2.12 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
  configuration: --enable-libmfx --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://premium-play.org:8000/domm0H56Cj/q3ODLP6C16/2826':
  Duration: N/A, start: 30200.274878, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
libva info: VA-API version 1.0.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[h264_qsv @ 0x2a89500] Selected ratecontrol mode is not supported by the QSV runtime. Choose a different mode.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Share your full ffmpeg command and log.

Comment: You may need `-look_ahead 0` before output file/stream argument.

Comment: This is my full ffmpeg command and error log :  https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/vp9XIzbeOuyXRuLBlLfSng

Comment: @halfelf can you tell me where I put -look_ahead 0 ?

Comment: Try the command at https://superuser.com/a/1259085/114058